# How can add screen support only for handsets and tablets <= 7' on android manifest

Tags: android, screen, android-manifest

Im doing this:

```
<compatible-screens>
<!-- all small size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<!-- all normal size screens -->
 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" /><!-- new screens S4, N5, ONE... -->

<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" /> <!-- 7 tablets... -->
</compatible-screens>
```

with this manifest I can ensure that all devices operate up to 7 inches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off-the-shelf list of device definitions in AVD includes two that are not filtered by your manifest:

**7.0" WSVGA (Tablet)**: Screen 7.0", 1024x600 large mdpi
**Nexus 7**: Screen 7.3", 800x1280 Large tvdpi

You cannot use **tvdpi** in xml, here is the workaround:

```
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
```